# Получить ближайшие записи по дате SQL

Tags: sql

Добрый день. Есть записи с типом date.  begin_registration и end_registration типа timestamp. Это период регистрации на семинар. Как получить все записи на которые открыта регистрация. Т.е. Сегодя 06 июня 2016 г., а начало регистрации от 05 июня 2016 г. по 21 июня 2016 г.
Как правильно составить SQL запрос

Comment: видимо что то типа `SYSDATE between begin_registration and end_registration`. SYSDATE заменить на функцию получающую текущую дату нужного типа в вашем диалекте SQL (который вы в вопросе не указали)

Comment: MySQL. наверно функция NOW

Comment: Ну да, `now()` или `curdate()` (только дата, без времени) или `current_timestamp()` (вы там что то про timestamp писали).

Answer (score 1):

В postgresql

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE (begin_registration, end_registration) OVERLAPS ('2016-06-05':DATE, '2016-06-21'::DATE);
```